# No passwords stored in Webview

Tags: password, webview

I have an ASUS tf101. Have rooted it and installed SQLite Editor. Have found the Webview file. There is listed some web adresses, but under passwords the fields are blank. 
I desperately need one of these passwords, but why are they not listed there?
The password for the spesific site was typed in the browser just a few weeks ago.

Comment: Webview file for which app?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Forgot Password option for the website. The passwords are encrypted and you can't find them like that.